# Regex to replace all characters except first 3

Tags: php, regex, regexp-replace

I have a requirement to replace the following strings in the given format through the regex. Any help would be appreciated.

1. johnsmith@gmail.com => johxxxxx@xxxx.xxx (All the characters should be replaced with x other than the first three, @, and dot (.)).
2. John Smith => Johx Smixx (All the characters should be replaced with x other than the first three characters from each letter)
3. 9876543210 => 987xxx3210 (All the characters should be replaced with x other than the first three and the last four)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The article title doesn't match the question. Define the logic for the three cases, are these 3 regexs or 1?

Comment: Why don't you simply use substr to take first 3 characters and then loop through the rest of the characters and turns them into * (except @ and .) ? is regex must?

Comment: By the way: On Stackoverflow you're usually supposed to post what you have tried so far yourself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. 

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(?<=...)[^@.]/', 'x', 'johnsmith@gmail.com');
johxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx
```

https://regex101.com/r/ASq1N2/1

2.

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(?<=\S{3})\S/', 'x', 'John Smith');
Johx Smixx
```

https://regex101.com/r/zqhwSg/1

3.

```
php > echo preg_replace('/(?<=.{3}).(?=.{4})/', 'x', '9876543210');
987xxx3210
```

https://regex101.com/r/ppmBUm/1

---

ad 1.
Approach:
a) I want to replace all individual characters that are not `@` or `.`
b) I want to make sure the character to be replaced is at least the 4th character in the string.
That means it has to have *at least 3 characters left of it*

a) To match a character I use the `[]` "character class" operator.
In it I can specify what characters to match. Or which characters **not** to match, if I start with `^`.
That's why `[^@.]` will match a single character that is **not** one of `@` or `.`.
(Note: `^` has a different meaning OUTside of `[]`).
b) we can look to the left by using a "look-behind" `(?=)` expression.
After the `=` I have to specify what I want to match. I want to match any 3 characters, so `...` will do. (as `.` outside of character classes matches any character)
(As alternative solution I could also use `.{3}` like I did in answer 3.,
which means "match any character, do that exactly 3 times")
Resulting in `(?=...)`

Now let's plug it together.
First look left to make sure the character that we will match has at least 3 others left of it. Then let's match the character.
`(?<=...)[^@.]`

Comment: Thanks Jay! You are a life saver. Any reference to master/learn the regex?

Comment: @MJ. :) Regex is like vim or a musical instrument. If you want to learn it, you have to confront yourself frequently and kind of seriously, or else learning progress will be almost non-existant; only the basics will stick. I basically use regex every day at work and hobbies, to find/match/format. But I also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex every now then. Maybe visit daily. Try to post answers and learn from answers of others :) Also if you see something new, look at documentation, try to *really* understand it. Create own examples. That's how e.g. I learned `\K` :D

Comment: @MJ. Since I don't know how new you are, I thought it might be helpful if I write out my thought process for at least 1). Don't know if it's actually helpful, but I added it. Also I realized that in 2) I could write `\S` (character that isn't a white Space character) instead of `[^\s]` (match character that is *not*: a white space character)

Answer (score 0):

In case you must use regex, this is how you do it for the email thing..

```
<?php
$regex = "/(\w{3})([^@]+)@([^\.]+)\.(.*)/";

$email = "johnsmith@gmail.com";

preg_match_all($regex, $email, $matches);


if(count($matches) == 5){
    $email = $matches[0][0];
    $email = str_replace($matches[2][0], str_repeat("*", strlen($matches[2][0])), $email);
    $email = str_replace($matches[3][0], str_repeat("*", strlen($matches[3][0])), $email);
    $email = str_replace($matches[4][0], str_repeat("*", strlen($matches[4][0])), $email);
    
    echo $email;
}

?>
```

For the name part you can do like this.. (regex will be kind complex)

```
<?php
$name = "John Smith";
$nameParts = array_map(function($element){
    return substr($element, 0, 3) . str_repeat("*", strlen($element) - 3);
}, explode(" ", $name));
$maskedName = implode(" ", $nameParts);

echo $maskedName;
?>
```

For the last one you can apply same kind of logic.

Comment: `Johx Smixx` is not produced from `substr($name, 0, 3) . str_repeat("*", strlen($name) - 3)`. This also doesn't address the integers, and won't scale for any other email address

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread it.. you wanted both first and last name to have first 3 characters only.. Let me update the code..

Comment: (Not my question, but yes, that is OPs intent)

Comment: Note: Interesting approach. However `str_replace()` may cause unwanted replacements. E.g. `abab@gmail.com` will become `a*a*@*****.***`, because the replaced part after the first 3 letters happens to be also contained within those 3 letters. Even more interesting, unwanted replacements can mess with the replacements later on. E.g. `ali.c@gmail.com` becomes `ali**@*******om` because `.c` matches twice and in turn prevents `com` from matching.